# Wordpress Query Posts From Category Post on Static Page

Tags: posts, pages, loop, blog, customization

So I'm trying to query some posts from 1 category only and it does seem to be working. I tried get_post() also but no luck and after awhile I just caved and used query_posts (which is apparently bad practice).  Here's my code:

```
<div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">
                <?php query_posts('slug=cat1'); ?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post">
                         <h1>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h1> 
                        <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
```

The second `endif;` is from above I have a test against the page slug. But from my understanding the query_posts should populate $post with all the posts from that category but I'm still getting posts from uncatagorized and another category so it's not filtering at all... Suggestions?

**Edit1** I tried using `cat=0` and `cat=1` also `cat=2` but the only one that actually filters is the `cat=1` which filters to uncategorized. All the others show all posts. Not sure why...

**Edit2** 
`query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'Category1', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );` returned with the "else" statement saying there was no posts and nothing fit my criteria. I pulled that straight from the codex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird Problem!, try the following:

- Make sure that the targeted categories are not empty.
- If you are using custom post type,include it in the query `'post_type'=>'advertisement'` for example.
- If the targeted categories are special taxonomies,make sure to include it in the query : `'term'=>'cars'` along with child `'cars'=>'toyota'`.

  - in this example and just to make it clear : cars is like category and toyota is like uncategorized.

One last thing:  trace the query by echoing the query to find out what is the exact arriving query:

`echo $query_string;`;
place it in the top of the page before the `<?php if ( have_pos...` and right after the `query_posts(..);`

please tell us the results of the query in case it didn't work.

Comment: what are the category name, category slug and category ID of the category that you are trying to retrieve? have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters ?

Comment: @Michael didn't get your question clearly, Would you explaining little more?

Comment: never mind - the question was directed at Howdy_McGee - I just posted it below the wrong reply ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Simple code to show all post when you dont have anything on your query_var (the output will be -1 to show all posts) and certain post by getting the query_var.

```
if(get_query_var('cat') == ''){
   $cat = (get_query_var('cat')) ? get_query_var('cat') : -1;}
else{
   $cat = (get_query_var('cat'));}
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged, 'cat' => $cat);
query_posts($args);
```

Hope it can helped you.

**Edited:** ofc you need to pass on your menu the 'cat' id into the URL.

**Edited2:**
codex page

> hooking into 'pre_get_posts' and altering the main query that way
>   using is_main_query
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

its the preferred way... but the example above works like a champ!

Just make sure you call wp_reset_query() after you're done de 2nd loop.

Comment: [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) should not be used to create secondary loops.

Comment: sry, i dont get it maybe im to fresh. Well for me this was the primary loop... although you just need to finish everyquery wp_reset_query() and everything should be fine i suppose.

Comment: Read the Codex page for `query_posts`. It is a bad way to modify the main Loop as well. `wp_reset_query` doesn't solve the issue. If it is the main query, using `query_posts` causes two queries to run when you only need one.

Comment: I think isnt an issue. But just bad practice. Codex suggests a lot of this double loop examples and recommend to end all open queries... seems bad practice that can be minimized but isnt a issue. Or it is and im see it wrong?

Comment: `query_posts` will work, sure, but it doubles the database load for the page. That is an issue, maybe not a fatal issue but an issue. Yes, I know the Codex uses `query_posts` a lot. It is community edited and much of that is probably years old.

Comment: ok s_ha_dum thanks. Gona manage the next loops with the pre_get_posts.